# Kernel does not support 64 bit cpu

Tags: dual-boot, kernel

Last night I installed ubuntu 22.04 onto my pc and chose the option to have 22.04 to run alongside my older 18.04.6 which all my documents and pictures are stored on as i didn't want to lose them, now when I boot up the pc it gives the option to load 18.04 but when I click on it, it says error: kernel doesn't support 64-bit cpu,s, error you need to load the kernel first, press any key to continue.
Please could anyone hep me with this as I don't want to lose all my documents.
Thank you, Kind regards
Steve

Boot options:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: could you take a picture of boot options and add to your question? and that of the error also,

Comment: Hi Andra, can you see the photos I've added, Thank you, Steve

Comment: What you can (almost) always do is boot from the 22.04 usb device, choose 'try Ubuntu' and backup your data from the 18.04 partition to a seperate partition or other usb device.

Comment: did you try "Advanced options for Ubuntu 18.04.6" (the last line) and boot some previous kernel?

Comment: Thank you all very much for taking the time to help with my question.
I thought I'd have to boot into my old Ubuntu 18.04.6 system separately from my new 22.04 Ubuntu, but no its not the case.
I have found the file containing all my data on my new 22.04 system, its listed as Parent folder /media/steven/then a long list of letters and numbers, and it amounts to 350GB containing all my data, well pleased.
Thanks again for your help
Best wishes
Steve